# Rewriting TSQL to eliminate a cursor

Tags: t-sql

Is there anyway to eliminate this cursor logic?

I need to iterate over @YearMonth (which will end up looking similar to this: “2015-01”, “2015-02”, “201503” (up until the current date)

```
DECLARE myCursor CURSOR
FOR SELECT DISTINCT(YearMonth) FROM Submissions
OPEN myCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @YearMonth
LOOP BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #EngagementCount (YearMonth, EngagmentCount)
            SELECT @YearMonth AS YearMonth COUNT(e.EngagementID) AS EngagementCount
            FROM Engagements AS e
            WHERE @YearMonth >= e.StartDate and @YearMonth < e.ExpiresOn
LOOP END
```

Comment: Come on format the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT YearMonth, COUNT(e.EngagementID) AS EngagementCount 
FROM Submissions s
INNER JOIN Engagements e ON s.YearMonth BETWEEN e.StartDate AND e.Expires
GROUP BY YearMonth
```

Comment: I would add Distinct Suqbuery for submissions SELECT YearMonth, COUNT(e.EngagementID) AS EngagementCount 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT YearMonth FROM Submissions) s
INNER JOIN Engagements e ON s.YearMonth BETWEEN e.StartDate AND e.Expires
GROUP BY YearMonth